# SQL Server group rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have table that have data like this

| OrdersDate | OrdersQuantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-10 | 40 |
| 2021-03-11 | 80 |
| 2021-03-12 | 63 |
| 2021-03-13 | 20 |
| 2021-03-14 | 80 |
| 2021-03-15 | 80 |
| 2021-03-16 | 70 |
| 2021-03-17 | 20 |
| 2021-03-18 | 80 |
| 2021-03-19 | 80 |
| 2021-03-20 | 80 |
| 2021-03-21 | 80 |
| 2021-03-22 | 80 |

I need to group this data by 10 rows in each started from first, but groups formed like 1-10 rows, then 2-11, then 3-12. So groups intersected. I tried add ROW_NUMBER and group rows somehow based on it, but because groups intersected I dont know how to specify group conditions.

I expect result like

| OrdersDate | OrdersQuantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1st group (from 2021-03-10 to 2021-03-19) | AVG() |
| 2nd group (from 2021-03-11 to 2021-03-20) | AVG() |
| 3rd group (from 2021-03-12 to 2021-03-21) | AVG() |
| 4th group (from 2021-03-13 to 2021-03-22) | AVG() |

I solved this with cursor but it works well only on small sample data, when I tried it on >2kk rows it took a lot of time.

Is there a way to group rows and calculate AVG of each group?

Comment: Expected results to go with your sample data, and your attempts will help us help you.

Comment: Are there gaps between the dates?

Comment: Yes, there can be gaps between dates

Comment: If there is a missing date between 2021-03-10 and 2021-03-19 is the 1st group from 2021-03-10 to 2021-03-19 or 2021-03-10 to 2021-03-20?

Comment: To what ever date 10 rows ahead from current row. That is why I tried to add rownumbers  to data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions that operate on each row and the next 9 rows to create the groups of 10:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT OrdersDate from_Date,
         MAX(OrdersDate) OVER (ORDER BY OrdersDate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 9 FOLLOWING) to_Date,
         AVG(1.0 * OrdersQuantity) OVER (ORDER BY OrdersDate ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 9 FOLLOWING) average_qty,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrdersDate) rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER () total_rows
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT from_Date, to_Date, average_qty 
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= total_rows - 9 OR rn = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=890b103be27b9c4b71df24ac94c3afef).

Comment: Thank you. This is great solution. One last question: can this query be modified to work with different groups. Like I have third column with product name and I need to group by ProductName and in each product calculate avg by your algorithm?

Comment: @Kostya you can use a PARTITION BY clause with AVG() window function if you want to create groups by any column. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#e-using-the-over-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use cte recursive to make a calendar table for your logic range date by `DATEADD` function, then use self-join by date range.

**Query 1**:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT MIN(OrdersDate) s_date,
         MAX(OrdersDate) e_date
  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day , 1 ,  s_date) ,e_date
  FROM CTE 
  WHERE DATEADD(day , 10 ,  s_date)  <= e_date
) 
SELECT CONCAT(t1.s_date,' to ' , t1.final_date) OrdersDate,
      AVG(t2.OrdersQuantity) OrdersQuantity
FROM (
  SELECT s_date,DATEADD(day , 9 ,  s_date) final_date
  FROM CTE
) t1 INNER JOIN T t2 
ON t2.OrdersDate BETWEEN t1.s_date AND t1.final_date
GROUP BY CONCAT(t1.s_date,' to ' , t1.final_date) 
option ( MaxRecursion 0 );
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b6b572/10/0)**:

```
|               OrdersDate | OrdersQuantity |
|--------------------------|----------------|
| 2021-03-10 to 2021-03-19 |             61 |
| 2021-03-11 to 2021-03-20 |             65 |
| 2021-03-12 to 2021-03-21 |             65 |
| 2021-03-13 to 2021-03-22 |             67 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE to first get the qualifying date range start dates using mod then grouping by the start and end dates concatenated:

```
with r as (
    select ordersdate StartDate, DateAdd(day,9,ordersdate) EndDate,
        DateAdd(day, Count(*) over() % 10, Min(ordersdate) over()) MaxStart
    from t
)
select Daterange, Avg(t.OrdersQuantity) OrdersQuantity
from r
cross apply (values( Concat(r.StartDate, ' to ', EndDate)))v(Daterange)
join t on t.ordersdate between StartDate and EndDate
where r.StartDate  < = r.MaxStart
group by Daterange
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d14ac9311280f69acf4c86a7d4f87db)